# Not working javascript code - some sort of cache problem?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, return

```
  Array.forEach((element) => {
    recipes.forEach((curr, index) => {
      found = true;
      item = element;
      if (!curr.ingredients.includes(element)) found = false;
      if (index + 1 === recipes.length && found === false) {
        console.log(element, false);
      } else if (index + 1 === recipes.length && found === true) {
        console.log(element, true);
        foundItem = element;
      }
    });
  });
  return foundItem;
```

Hello, guys... I am trying to debug such code... What is happening is that, as you can see in the picture down below, My code is returning me "açúcar", "calabresa", and "cerveja".
[Image where you can see the output from my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvikl.png)

However, it is not what I mean since I am looping through a JSON list that happens to have ingredients for several different recipes...
Such as follows

```
  "recipes": [
    {
      "id": "00832498-3acc-4bde-9d89-77eacef26680",
      "title": "Excelente pudim de milho",
      "ingredients": [
        "abóbora",
        "aveia",
        "azeite",
        "açúcar",
        "cerveja",
        "frango",
        "milho",
        "morango",
        "vinho"
      ],
      "price": 78.53
    },
    {
      "id": "008b345d-8f7c-427d-988b-4f238b8315f2",
      "title": "Excelente bolo de azeite",
      "ingredients": [
        "abóbora",
        "aveia",
        "azeite",
        "açúcar",
        "frango",
        "vinho"
      ],
      "price": 82.55
    },
    {
      "id": "00d14194-f223-447e-86a0-b535c451d53f",
      "title": "Exuberante coxinha de vinho",
      "ingredients": [
        "abóbora",
        "azeite",
        "açúcar",
        "calabresa",
        "cerveja",
        "chuchu",
        "frango",
        "morango",
        "uva",
        "vinho"
      ],
```

What I want to get is açucar, since is the only ingredient which is present in all of the recipes...
As for me, it seems like there is some sort of cache-related problem here

Comment: Could you explain are you trying to do with that code?

Comment: Ok, @GuillermoGarcíaLópez, I can... I am trying to find some ingredient that is present in all of the recipes...

The recipes are in the JSON file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could change your code to this:

```
Array.forEach((element) => {
  const isIncluded = recipes.every(recipe => recipe.ingredients.includes(element));
  if (isIncluded) {
    // Do something with the ingredient or the element.
  }
});
return foundItem;
```

The every method checks that every recipe includes the ingredient that you pass to it.

Answer (score 1):

if you have access to lodash you can make this really clean

```
import { intersection } from 'lodash'

getCommonIngredients = (recipes) => {
  const ingredients = recipes.map(recipe => recipe.ingredients)
  return intersection(...ingredients)
}
```